# How to rename branch names on svn when migrating to git

Tags: git, branch, rename

I have few multi module projects which i have to migrate to git and generate a parent aggregator project out of it. The projects on svn has different naming convention on svn , and i want to rename the branches to make it standard through out the code structure.

```
ex- project1
branches - project1_121
           213
           project1_454

project2
branches - project2_121
           project2_213
           project2_454
```

i want to rename these branches to have a number common across multiple projects. The branches should be renamed in a manner such that

```
project1_121 and project_121 will become 121.
```

Steps i performed :

```
git svn clone "svn url"
now i want to change the branch name:
so for that i need to checkout the branches and rename. As i have hundreds of branches in each proect. Is there any alternative to do it easily and in a less error prone way.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can modify git svn clone to modify branch names but you could write a script to rename branches.

This will rename any branch in the format abc_123 to 123

```
for x in `git branch`; do 
  new_name=`echo $x |grep -E [0-9]*$`
  git branch -m $x $new_name
done
```